# Barchart when the levels of a categorical variables are in different columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which the levels of a categorical variable are in different columns (group), and I was wondering:

1. How I can create a bar chart across the levels of age including the calculated percentages.
2. How I can compare/calculate the pvalues for comparing the cells around age levels (for example
   comparing percentages corresponding to 22,23,24,44; comparing percentages corresponding to 34,35,36,66; and the same for the third group)

Data:

```
   Age<-c(1,2,3,4)
       group1<- c(22,23,24,44)
       group2<-c(34,35,36,66)
       group3<-c(44,55,66,67)
       A<-data.frame(Age,group1,group2,grou3)
```

Comment: This is a stats question rather than a programming question, so should really be posted over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), our sister site for stats questions. However, it's not really possible to test the significance of differences in proportions / percentages without knowing the raw numbers involved. If you test 10 women and find 4 of them prefer milk in their tea, then test 10 men and 5 of them prefer milk in their tea, there is no real evidence of a difference between the two, but 400/1000 and 500/1000 would be very good evidence of a difference.

Comment: @
Allan Cameron, thank you so much for the reply. I modified the question. I would be so thankful for your help in advance

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you want percentages to be calculated? Can you include your code where you generate the p-values you mentioned?